# How to define prismatic schema for interleaved types?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, plumatic-schema

Lets assume I have the following sequence:

```
'[ 
    SomeMandatorySymbol 
    AnotherMandatorySymbol 
    123 
    "mandatory string" 
    2 "a" 
    9 "c" 
    11 "f" 
    23 "x" ]
```

e.g.  `[(one Symbol) (one Symbol) (one Int) (one Str)  ... ]`

What should I insert instead ... to have valid schema for variable length interleaved ints and strings?